# Is there an esLint rule to avoid separated require() groups?

Tags: javascript, eslint, require, commonjs

I would like to avoid having multiples `require` groups but have them all on the same one.
There is a way to do so (in imports) with tsLint using `ordered-imports` and setting the property `grouped-imports` to true. But haven't found the equivalent in esLint.

I mean, if I have

```js
const { a, b, c} = require('./my/path.js');

const {d, e} = require('./my/other/path2.js');

// this is the same path 
const {f} = require('./my/path.js');
```

I would like to have an eslint warn of this to fix it.

How can this be done?

Comment: [*eslint-plugin-import*](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-import) has all the rules you could wish for, such as complaining about duplicate imports, but I doubt it works on commonjs `require` calls

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify whether you specifically refer to `require()`, `import`, or both. The answer will depend on that.

Comment: @Bergi thanks for your comments, I wanna do it with `require` specifically, so I edited it as you suggested.